# How to append IDs in array to DIVs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array with 9 strings below:

```
var boardBox  = ['#box1', 
                 '#box2',
                 '#box3',
                 '#box4',
                 '#box5',
                 '#box6',
                 '#box7',
                 '#box8',
                 '#box9'];
```

I want to append each ID to 9 DIVs that are dynamically being added to the DOM as below

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        $( ".row" ).append( "<div class='col-md-4'></div>" );   
    }
```

Is append the way to do this? I tried it and its not running. I tried

```
$( ".row" ).text(boardBox[i]).appendTo('<div></div>');
```

Comment: try,
 for (var i = 0; i < boardBox.length; i++){
  $( ".row" ).append( "<div class='col-md-4' id='"+ boardBox[i]+"' ></div>" );   
}

Comment: Do you really want `#` in the id, or because it is id you've added it in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var boardBox = ['#box1',
    '#box2',
    '#box3',
    '#box4',
    '#box5',
    '#box6',
    '#box7',
    '#box8',
    '#box9'];
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < boardBox.length; i++) {
    html += "<div id="+boardBox[i]+ " class='col-md-4'>"+boardBox[i]+"</div>"
}

$(".row").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: Now, as the answer is accepted put some efforts to explain it as OP seems to be naive

Answer (score 2):

You can use `i` to access array element by index and concatenate that value as content of div you are appending to row:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  $( ".row" ).append( "<div class='col-md-4' >" + boardBox[i] + "</div>" );   
}
```

Comment: Can you move `append` outside of `for`, it'll save 8 DOM manipulations

Comment: @Tushar: how come?? op also need to append the content in each iteration.

Comment: `var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    str + = "<div class='col-md-4' >" + boardBox[i] + "</div>";
}
$('.row').append(str);`

Comment: @Tushar: yup. that can be done when iteration count is more. will not make much difference for fewer divs

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, I still feel minimum `DOM manipulation` is better practice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of another for loop you can make use of it like:

```
$.each(boardBox, function(i, id){ // get the each id here
   $('<div>', {
      id: id, // apply it here
      class:"col-md-4",
      text:"test div"
   }).appendTo('.row'); // append element here.
});
```

Comment: Can you move `appendTo` outside of `each`, it'll save 8 DOM manipulations

Comment: @Tushar that doesn't create any issue, because todays browser are so fast this is not an issue.

Comment: I'm not talking about issue here, I'm talking about _optimization_, what if OP wants to add 100s of divs

Comment: Yes, but sometime you've to add elements dynamically

Comment: _Can you move appendTo outside of each, it'll save 8 DOM manipulations_ does it just for two answers posted or you don't see this with Mlind's answer too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90773/discussion-between-tushar-and-jai).

Comment: @Tushar don't get it wrong but discussion boards are blocked here @ my place.

Comment: Ok, I also don't know how that can be done, but I'm curious if that can be done when you create new DOM elements using jQuery as you've done. And regarding other answer you pointed, it's really easy to create a string, concat elements and then after `for`, `append` that in DOM

Comment: @Tushar that depends on the requirement, people knows how to bind any event on dynamically created elements but with `for` loop you have to bind that while with this you can make use of builtin `on` method to bind the events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)**

```js
var boardBox = ['#box1',
  '#box2',
  '#box3',
  '#box4',
  '#box5',
  '#box6',
  '#box7',
  '#box8',
  '#box9'
];

boardBox.forEach(function(v) {
// iterating over array  
  $('<div/>', {
    text: v,
    id: v
  })
  // generating element with content and id as array value
  .appendTo('.row');
  // appendding div to '.row'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=row></div>
```